# Performance based on where we implement the methods of a class

Tags: c++, class, c++17

On a large scale, is Case 3 the slowest in time execution?

Case 1: methods defined outside the class

```cpp
class A{
    int a, b;

public:
    A(int, int);
    int add();
};

A::A(int _a, int _b){a=_a; b=_b;}
int A::add(){return a+b;}
```

Case 2: methods defined within the class

```cpp
class A{
    int a, b;

public:
    A(int _a, int _b){a=_a; b=_b;}
    int add(){return a+b;}
};
```

Case 3: mix of case 1 and 2

```cpp
class A{
    int a, b;
public:
    A(int _a, int _b){a=_a; b=_b;}
    int add();
};
int A::add(){return a+b;}
```

Comment: What did you find out when you measured them?

Comment: All 3 could end up being optimized to the same exact code by your compiler.

Comment: @eerorika using `std::chrono` doesn't really help (I keep getting 0 second as a result) and to know if in a large scale if it will be the same time execution for the 3 cases, I wanted to know if someone knows something about those 3 different implementations

Comment: @drescherjm is it the case behind the scene by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all exactly the same, but only if the methods are called within the same translation unit where they're defined.

What really matters here isn't whether a function is defined within the class definition or outside.  What matters is whether a function's full definition is visible to the compiler at the point you call that function.  That generally means the function's definition must reside in the same translation unit as the code calling the function.  Defining a class's member functions directly in the class definition itself is one way to make that happen.  If you define the member functions outside the class definition, and put them in a header file that gets included into multiple translation units, you'll need to use the `inline` keyword.

If functions' definitions are visible from the point those functions are called, the compiler can easily inline calls to the functions.  For example, given the following:

```
A a(one, two);
int three = a.add();
```

If the definitions of the `A::A(int, int)` and `A::add` are visible, then the compiler can easily reduce that operation to a couple of simple assembly instructions.  i.e.:

```
mov eax, esi
add eax, edx
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/fNtA5q).  Notice that the code generated for `main` is exactly the same in all three cases.  The compiler can see that, once all is said and done, that code is equivalent to `three = one + two` and compile it as such.  The compiler may even be able to do the calculations at compile time and replace that all with a constant, if the inputs are known at that point.

But if the functions definitions *aren't* visible, the compiler can't do any of those optimizations (barring link-time-optimization maybe).  It would have to actually insert `call`s to the functions for the linker to later resolve.  That involves some extra overhead.

---

So why don't we just put all of our code in headers?  One reason is that the extra overhead from a function call is very small.  If the function does any non-trivial amount of work it's likely that the function's runtime will dwarf the extra time it takes to perform a function call.  Forcing the compiler to do all of that extra work can also increase compile times.

Even still, header-only libraries that do exactly that are popular these days due mainly to their ease of use and possible performance benefits.